# Stream an entrySet to groupingBy instead of keySet

Tags: java, lambda

I was watching a [JavaOne video By Venkat Subramanian about lambdas](http://bitly.com/2CHsAlW).

He had an example like this:

```
Map<String, Integer>    scores  = new HashMap<>();
    scores.put("Jack", 12);
    scores.put("Jill", 15);
    scores.put("Tom", 11);
    scores.put("Darla", 15);
    scores.put("Nick", 15);
    scores.put("Nancy", 11);
    System.out.println(groupByScores(scores));
```

with this method:

```
public static Map<Integer, List<String>> groupByScores(Map<String, Integer> scores) {
    return scores.keySet().stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(scores::get));
}
```

The one thing that's a little bothersome about this is that it's essentially iterating over the `keySet`, calling map.get(key) for each key. But that's an *antipattern* in plain non-lambda code.

How can I get the same result, producing a "peopleByAge" map, but by iterating over the `entrySet` instead of the `keySet`?  The hard part is obviously everything past `stream()`.

Comment: but isn't map.get(key) an O(1) operation anyway?

Comment: @Solace But even then, there has to be hash computation and more implementation specific stuff. I agree that it feels pretty unnecessary given that there is an `entrySet` capability.

Comment: @David: Can you link to the video? Otherwise it's irrelevant.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
return scores.entrySet().stream()
           .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getValue,
                    Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getKey,
                                       Collectors.toList())));
```

Comment: Your indentation is weird. Please don't collapse multiple closing parentheses onto the end of one line: are you sure that it means what you intended?

Comment: I don't understand the last part of your comment :) I know what it does.

Comment: No one can be certain that your four closing parentheses are correct without either counting them or using the compiler to do the same thing. That makes your code unintuitive for ordinary people, and exemplifies the reason for proper indentation. Your code is poor because it doesn't represent its function well. Think about extracting `scores.entrySet().stream()` separately and avoid "clever" code.

Comment: This is not clever. Its just what OP asked for :)